# Node server on EC2 only works through IP address and not domain name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Node server listening to port 3000.
When I try to access it by ip address it works fine but when I try domainname.com:3000 I'm unable to connect.
The node server is on an Amazon EC2 instance using a load balancer and Route 53 for DNS.
I've enabled port 3000 in the Security group.

I feel like it might be an Apache config problem but not sure.
Others have had similar problems but haven't been able to find a solution looking at those questions.

Comment: Can you confirm that your host name domainname.com returns the proper IP#?

Comment: Have you enabled port 3000 on the ELB's Security Group as well?
Are you trying to connect directly to the EC2 instance's public IP or via the ELB?

Comment: ELB is using the same Security Group. The EC2 public IP is different from the 2 IP addresses I get when doing a who.is on the domain name... and I can't connect to the node server using those IP addresses but Apache works fine on all IPs and the domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Load Balancer's Listeners were not set up to listen to port 3000.